# How do i get number of tolls between two points in google direction api?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-directory-api

I have to get numbers of tolls when driving from point A to B. I am using google direction API for this.
The API provides information weather the road is toll road or not in html_instructions tag in response ,but a tolls road may contain number to tolls,Is there a way to count them.

Comment: I think question is based on android, which I realized now.I have answered in javascript .Hope this gives some hint

Comment: @Deep3015 Hi thanks for the answer,but i have a question can single toll road contain multiple tolls?

Comment: i am not getting your doubt. what is _single toll road_ ,is it start to destination path or it is a sub part of route. If it is sub part ,then it is not possible for _can single toll road contain multiple tolls_

Comment: @Deep3015 i have this doubt because i know a route that has multiple tolls (ie haldwani to delhi) ,but the respone is showing only one toll road,

Comment: may be it is not updated in google records  or it may be local taxes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [directions-draggable](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-draggable) code. In order to calculate the number of tolls in the way , you have to find them in `myroute.legs[i].steps[j].instructions` which is the result of direction display services. To find `toll road` I am using regular expression

[Check fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/fbuuqkuk/)

Code below

```js
function containsWord(string, word) {
    return new RegExp('(?:[^.\w]|^|^\\W+)' + word + '(?:[^.\w]|\\W(?=\\W+|$)|$)').test(string);
}
function computeTotalDistance(result) {
  var total = 0;
  var myroute = result.routes[0];
  var totalTolls=0;
  for (var i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
  //console.log(myroute.legs[i].steps);
  for(var j=0;j<myroute.legs[i].steps.length;j++){
  //console.log(myroute.legs[i].steps[j].instructions);
  if(containsWord(myroute.legs[i].steps[j].instructions.toLowerCase(), 'toll road')){
  totalTolls+=1;
  }

  }
    total += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
  }
  total = total / 1000;
  document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total + ' km';
  document.getElementById('totalTollCount').innerHTML = totalTolls ;
}
```

Comment: could have a problem with this solution, in part of the rout with more than one toll it only will count one.

Comment: @Deep, Is there a possibility of two or more tolls within a single step ?